# php- data not entered to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to enter 3 different data to a mysql database 'pages'
The first 2 data is submitted to the database but the third 'dname' is not.

 The `$_SESSION['dname']` contains the value to be added to the column 'dname'

 The php looks like:

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $menulabel = $_POST['menulabel'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $dname = $_SESSION['dname'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO pages (menulabel, content, dname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $menulabel, $content, $dname);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    if ($statement->error)
    {
        die('Database query failed: ' . $statement->error);
    }

    $creationWasSuccessful = $statement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
    if ($creationWasSuccessful)
    {
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
}
```

The mysql table:

```
     $query_pages = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, menulabel VARCHAR(50), content TEXT, dname VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    $databaseConnection->query($query_pages);
```

The php successfully adds the 'menulabel' and 'content' to the table and continues leaving the 'dname' NULL.

 Please help, this is my first time with php.

Comment: Have you verified what $dname contains? do a  `var_dump($dname)` and tell us what is returned by that.

Comment: Yup, the header of the page contains an `echo` to display the dname and it works

Comment: If you put `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php, and try to run it again, does it generate any error messages for you? If so, could you post them to us? Also, can you post where/how you're setting `$_SESSION['dname']` at?

Comment: @Ross Also if everything you saying is true, then this probably wouldn't help, but just in case, post the code where you set $_SESSION['dname']. Update this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy. This should fix your issue. Instead of throwing the object into the params, utilize it in the query instead.

```
$menulabel = $_POST['menulabel'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$dname = $_SESSION['dname'];
$query = "INSERT INTO pages (menulabel, content, dname) VALUES (?, ?, '$dname')";

$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('ss', $menulabel, $content);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
```

Comment: The session.php is included in the page. $_SESSION['dname'] contains the value I need. In the header there is an echo to display the value of $_SESSION['dname'] and that works.

Comment: I tried adding an input text field with the value of $_SESSION['dname']. This worked. I tried using POST method to post the value of the input field just like the menulabel and content. But this didn't work. It shows no error. The menulabel and content to the database but not dname. It has a value but it is not going into the database

Comment: I've updated my answer above. Give that a shot, and it should work out a lot better for you. If that doesn't work, let me know what value you get from 'dname' in your echo. Also, post up your inputs for me, and we'll get it figured out. If the above code works for you, then you won't have to utilize the inputs for it.